# AWS S3 Caching Static hosting but updating bucket contents via github workflow

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, github-actions, amazon-cloudfront

I've build a github workflow config for my react application which deploys directly to s3. I see that the bucket contents are getting updated but the histed static website on that bucket didn't get updated . I tried creating cloudfront invalidation as well but it didn't work. Can anyone help me with this issue ?

here's my ci.yml file

```
name: App name

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - development
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - development
jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    name: Lint
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18'
      - run: yarn
      - run: yarn lint
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    needs: lint
    name: Test
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18'
      - run: yarn
      - run: yarn test
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    needs: test
    name: Deploy
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn
      - name: Build the project
        run: yarn build
      - name: Cache the build directory
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: dist
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ hashFiles('yarn.lock') }}
      - name: Deploy to S3
        run: | 
          echo "GITHUB_REF: $GITHUB_REF"
          if [ "$GITHUB_REF" = "refs/heads/development" ] || [ "$GITHUB_REF" = "refs/heads/main" ]; then
            echo "Deploying to S3"
            if [ "$GITHUB_REF" = "refs/heads/main" ]; then
              aws s3 sync ./dist s3://app-frontend-prod
              echo "Deployment completed"
            else
              aws s3 sync ./dist s3://app-frontend-dev
              echo "Deployment completed"
            fi 
          else
            echo "Branch not configured for deployment."
            exit 1
          fi
        shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_REGION: 'us-west-2'
```

Comment: I haven't tried automating it, but manual cloudfront invalidation of static html files does work.  You might want to add details on the "it didn't work" part so that someone using github workflow has the info needed to help.  If it makes sense / is possible you might split the invalidation into a separate action and focus on just that code?  That also helps someone to help you.

Comment: Definitely sounds like cloudfront caching to me.   Assets whose content will change without the URL changing can be configured to cache less aggressively with s3 Cache-Control data: `aws s3 cp --cache-control 'max-age=30, must-revalidate, public' index.html 's3://--your--s3--bucket--/'`

Comment: @erik258 can you please elaborate more on the piece of code you've shared.

Comment: @DaveS I added Invalidation object path in my cloudfront to be /* , but that also didn't resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions, Dave and Erik . Cheers

Comment: CloudFront will respect Cache-Control headers set on individual s3 objects.  If you set it appropriately you won't have to invalidate cache all the time, that's my point.  If you're using webpack or similar to pack assets, you may have only a few URLs that aren't unique (like index.html)

Answer (score 0):

So this issue was due to build folder getting cached while deploying on s3. I resolved it by first deleting all the prior object by using --recursive flag and then uploading the entire build folder again.

```
name: App name

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - development
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - development
jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    name: Lint
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18'
      - run: yarn
      - run: yarn lint
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    needs: lint
    name: Test
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18'
      - run: yarn
      - run: yarn test
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    needs: test
    name: Deploy
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn
      - name: Build the project
        run: yarn build
      - name: Deploy to S3
        run: | 
          echo "GITHUB_REF: $GITHUB_REF"
          if [ "$GITHUB_REF" = "refs/heads/development" ] || [ "$GITHUB_REF" = "refs/heads/main" ]; then
            echo "Deploying to S3"
            if [ "$GITHUB_REF" = "refs/heads/main" ]; then
              aws s3 rm s3://app-frontend-prod --recursive
              aws s3 sync dist s3://app-frontend-prod
              echo "Deployment completed"
            else
              aws s3 rm s3://app-frontend-dev --recursive
              aws s3 sync dist s3://app-frontend-dev
              echo "Deployment completed"
            fi 
          else
            echo "Branch not configured for deployment."
            exit 1
          fi
        shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_REGION: 'us-west-2'
```

this is the updated yml file